# Equality of two sets in measure theory, with finite function for almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, almost-everywhere

I'm currently solving exercise 10 of chapter 2 of Stein's Real Analysis. The problem is given as follows.

[image]

What I'm struggling to is the first part :
$$\bigcup_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}F_k = \{x : f(x) > 0\}$$

The right direction is trivial because $F_k \subset \{x : f(x) > 0\}$ for all $k$. The thing is the left direction. Since $f$ has infinite values (on the set of $0$ measure), I think I have to consider the case $x$ with $f(x) = \infty$. But I can't assure that such $x$ is included in some of the $F_k$ because the value $f(x)$ of all elements $x$ in $F_k$ has finite values. The contraposition $\bigcap_k F_k^c \subset \{x : f(x) = 0 \}$ isn't clear as well.

So, any comments regarding the above statements would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think the equality is not literally going to hold but rather to be seen as almost-sure equality. The set of points in the RHS not in the LHS is null

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know there was a reply. Yeah I agree with your idea. Thank you.